# I can't see the object in perspective mode?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]
[image]

I'm working on an environment project with geometry nodes, and I don't know what happened. I can only see the object through the camera, but when I change the view to top view or perspective, it's gone. I can't see the object, I try to zoom in or out, whatever I do, I can't see it, but if I change the area, for example, go to the modeling area, I can see it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select your terrain mesh and then use *View > Frame Selected*.

[image]

Comment: thank you dear it shows now